# removeClass not working in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have set up a `Template.inquiry.events({` function in meteor.js that takes click data for buttons and adds a class to them.  This is working fine.  What is not working, is when I try to have the click remove the class.

It looks like this:

```
Template.inquiry.events({
    'click .button': function(event){

        var button_id=event.currentTarget.id

        report = false;
        consult = false;
        contract = false; 

        $("#" + button_id).addClass('selected');

        if(button_id == 'report' && report == false) {
            report = true;
            $("#" + button_id).addClass('selected');
        }
        else if(button_id == 'consult' && consult == false) {
            consult = true;
            $("#" + button_id).addClass('selected');
        }
        else if(button_id == 'contract' && contract == false) {
            contract = true;
            $("#" + button_id).addClass('selected');
        }
        else if(button_id == 'report' && report == true) {
            report = false;
            $("#" + button_id).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else if(button_id == 'consult' && consult == true) {
            consult = false;
            $("#" + button_id).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else if(button_id == 'contract' && contract == true) {
            contract = false;
            $("#" + button_id).removeClass('selected');
        }

    }
});
```

The first three "ifs" are working fine, but the removeClass ifs are not working.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each click `report` `consult` and `contract` are `false` so "else if" where you check `report == true` can not trigger. If you want store states between events use `Session` or `ReactiveVar` or just `Template.instance()` properties like

```
Template.inquiry.onCreated(function() {
    this.states = {};
    this.states.report = false;
});
...

    else if(button_id == 'consult' && !Template.instance().states.report) {
        Template.instance().states.report = true;
        $("#" + button_id).addClass('selected');
    }
    else if(button_id == 'report' && Template.instance().states.report) {
        Template.instance().states.report = false;
        $("#" + button_id).removeClass('selected');
```

Comment: Can I store these values in my db? (the true or false variable)

Comment: Why do you need to store it in DB? It's about UI as I can see, so it's better to use client part. If you want to save state between reload you can use local storage of user's browser.